# Automating image compression in Chrome with PowerShell and AutoHotkey

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, autohotkey, compression

I want to automatically compress images I download through Chrome. As a  superuser-in-training, I have tried using PowerShell but need further guidance. Additionally, I almost got AutoHotkey to work with a command line compression software called [Pingo](https://css-ig.net/pingo). Initially, it worked, but then it stopped working after I attempted to make changes. I'm currently stumped and in need of guidance or suggestions to troubleshoot and continue the process. Or find another way.
This is the AutoHotkey script i tried. Unsure if it's still working:

```
; Compress existing images in the folder
Loop, Files, %folder%\*.*
{
    if (A_LoopFileExt in ".jpg,.png,.bmp")
    {
        Run, "C:\Users\JohnPC\Documents\TOOLS\ping64\pingo.exe" -s9 "%A_LoopFileFullPath%",, Hide
    }
}

; Monitor the folder for new image files and compress them
Loop
{
    FileCreateDir, %folder%
    Loop, Files, %folder%\*.*
    {
        if (A_LoopFileExt in ".jpg,.png,.bmp")
        {
            Run, "C:\Users\JohnPC\Documents\TOOLS\ping64\pingo.exe" -s9 "%A_LoopFileFullPath%",, Hide
        }
    }
    Sleep, 5000 ; Check for new files every 5 seconds (adjust as needed)
}
```

I've also tried PowerShell for download folder monitoring of images for compression. No luck.

Comment: If you'd like to troubleshoot a script, we'll need to see the script and the changes which broke it. If you're looking for a bypass or another solution, check my answer.

Comment: Hello, please don't ever use statements like "no luck" or "doesn't work" on this network, instead **accurately** describe what's not working.

Comment: You really going to hyper focus on that, Despite having already accurately described what's not working in the whole body of text I've provided? No luck and doesn't work, are simple colloquial flare; or "contractions" that Humans, use. Try it sometime.

Comment: @JohnTry I gotta join Destroy666 on this; "but then it stopped working" don't help us, as much of the exact error. Did it failed? maybe a file was'nt in place, or maybe you've forgot to close some brackets.... "after I attempted to make changes" what changes? Do you have the original script? These will help a lot.

Comment: Also, I see that you're creating a folder named "%folder" in the middle of the script, while you're already within "%folder"-folder. Maybe it's redundant?

Comment: Im stuck so im asking chatgpt at this point and its giving me wrong answers. its almost helping but not totally.

Comment: @JohnTry you can try to not be rude for a kind request on a website you misunderstand, from what I see. Actual effort of solving the problem needs to be shown, not some copy pastes from RNG wheel called ChatGPT which you presumably didn't test properly, looking at the reply. I was going to show an exemplary solution and kept the tab for later but after reading that message - no thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AHK with a far more known program like IrfanView.

According to [the KB](https://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/IrfanView_Command_Line_Options), you should run something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" /resize=(w,h)
```

The only part left is finding the latest picture in "downloads" ( or whatever folder ) and choose that one - [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675658/powershell-get-childitem-most-recent-file-in-directory):

```
gci path | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
```

Comment: I provided the script i was using. Unsure if its still working. but there it is. Can you make sense of it? And Irfanview, i dont like its compression and had past problems with it. I may revisit it if desperate.

Comment: I'm unsure what caused the problem, so I really can't be certain further details would be anymore helpful.

Comment: I tried Powershell, but Im not familiar with powershell. Less familiar with AHK's , but through using gpt and googling I've found that script. That's as far as I can get on my own.

Comment: Sorry, offered a edit, rather than a comment.

I meant to say, better compression with Pingo. I'm sure the problem is my childlike grasp of powershell and batch , and not Pingo. I've tested some basic commands with it, and its functioning.

Comment: I commented on the question on the top.  Please try to describe the problem as best you can. Try to see some "bountied" questions for examples of "How a question should look like". These details will help us a lot :)

Comment: BTW did not knew irfan's compression was lacking haha

Comment: Pretty bad compared to Pingo in my time image editing.  I think i need a pure powershell solution. And not include batch.  Far as describe the ive done all I can there. Im hoping others can pivot to the solution. My attempts are easily inferred. Describing further, with needless info about haphazard attempts only holds this up. I come to these forums for assistance and advice. Not to dish out my ignorance.